# How to add link for my application from contacts quick menu

Tags: android, dialog, android-manifest, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

I want to write application which is connected with Contacts.

Scenario :

1. Enter to phone Contacts
2. We choose Contact item

[image]

3. Click on MyApp (The icon should be available only for contacts with numbers)
4. See the contact numbers so the user could click one any of them
5. My app will open.

This is where I got so far:
I added the following to the manifest file -

```
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/name" />
        </intent-filter>
```

The result is that I can see MyApp icon for all contacts instead of just these with phone numbers and when I select it I can see the contact name instead of its available numbers.

[image]

What I have to add to AndroidManifest in order do to see the contacts phone numbers or put a custom text there?

- Adding my own contacts with new MIMETYPE is not an option for me...

Answer (score 3):

Check my question/answer that may help you, did work for me.

[Integrate my app with Contact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479352/integrate-my-app-with-contact)

Hope that helps

Comment: weird, share some code if you like, because I was able to add my  app in QuickContactBadge using that code.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this mime type "vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2" instead of "vnd.android.cursor.item/name"