# Add application in contacts

Tags: android, android-activity, android-contacts

I want to show my app like this in contacts and want to open if clicked.[image]

I tried searched and found many solutions but didn't understand how i can add my app inside the contact. Found something like change mimetype, account name using contacts provider.

[Found Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479352/integrate-my-app-with-contact)
But still confused. Please help... I am new in android programming...

Comment: Ok good luck with that. You haven't actually asked a question though, so good luck with your app. Flag to close. I want a nice lunch.

Comment: Ha ha ha Very funny. bone appetit.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer. We can achieve this by using sync adapter. It creates account to sync data.
here are some links:

[This is Google example for sync adapter](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html)

[This is another developer example !](http://www.c99.org/2010/01/23/writing-an-android-sync-provider-part-2/)

[Running Sync Adapter](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/running-sync-adapter.html)