# Integrate my app with Default Android Contacts Manager

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent, android-contacts

I am a beginner in android development.

I wish to implement a feature in MY APP where in when a user clicks on contacts avatar my app icon is visible and when user clicks on app icon it would provide a feature to send current location to that contact as an sms.

The answer here is not much descriptive: [Integrate my app with Contact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479352/integrate-my-app-with-contact)

Expected view in contacts popup
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBFp5.jpg "

I really expect a descriptive answer as in what file and where code has to be added to make this thing work.

Apologies for being a newbie