# Add custom link to Android Contacts

Tags: java, android, contacts

I managed to add a custom "Button" to each one of my contacts using the code in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479352/integrate-my-app-with-contact), but everytime i'm clicking on the "Button", there's an exception like "application not found". Why doesn't it recognize my application?

How to fix that?

Comment: What's the **exact** exception and full stacktrace?

Comment: I can't see what exactly is going wrong, cuz its happening outside of the application.

When i click the button inside the contact i selected theres only written that no application has been found.

(I think it doesnt know which application it should open)?

Comment: Sorry, you said there's an exception, how do you know that?

Comment: Because it's telling me "application not found" ^^..

Comment: Heres a picture: [link](http://de.tinypic.com/r/2qwekhf/8)
If i click on the red point (somewhere inside the row) then it should normally start my app, but instead it's saying "application not found"

Comment: *Saying* where? Be more specific.

Comment: Examine LogCat and look for the errors associated with your "application not found" message": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: When i'm in the default Contacts-App, there, see picture.

And i can't receive any Logcat-thingys from there, because lets say its outside the app, at this point the app isn't even started or active.