# Integrate my app which contacts manager

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I want to display my app's icon in the contact info as a shortcut. The same way as google+, fb, whatsapp does.

I found this question: [Display the app icon if the contact is associated with the application in phone address book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21701017/display-the-app-icon-if-the-contact-is-associated-with-the-application-in-phone)

And its very similar to what I want to do, but using Apache Cordova. Any ideas how can i do it?
I tried adding my app deeplink in contacts IMS using the contacts plugin, but no success so far.

Comment: Have you found an answer

Answer (score -1):

[Maybe this will help a bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479352/integrate-my-app-with-contact). Give it a try!
This module is on my to-do list but i've kept it aside for a while...
I'll post if i'm able to do it. Please do the same!

Comment: I didn't understand very much. In this link, he did add a custom IM in the contacts, but how it calls a specific app with it?

Comment: provide only answers if you're sure, that they are going to help the user. Your answer doesn't consider any cordova behaviours. It belongs to a native application as far as i understood it.