# Integrate an react native app with the contacts

Tags: java, android, react-native

I'm using react-native to make an multiplatform VOIP Dialer, and i'm facing difficuties to integrate my app with the default contacts list of the o.s (Android on the below example)

[image]

I didn't tried anything already because i dont know Java (For android) neither objective-c (For IOS). So i was hoping there's a module for that

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this anwser [Integrate my app with Contact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479352/integrate-my-app-with-contact) , it shows how to do it with Java at an Android App.

Regards,